# boost lockfree use user define type

Tags: c++, boost, lock-free

I tried to use the boost lockfree library. However, there is an error `invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘boost::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<false>’` when I set the template parameter to user define type.
Is there any to resolve it?

```
typedef struct TMsgBuffer
   {
      char m_puBuffer[512];
      size_t m_iBufferLen;
   } tMsgBuffer;

boost::lockfree::fifo<tMsgBuffer> fifo;
```

Comment: Lockfree is not part of standard boost.  Where are you getting it?  What file/line number is the compiler giving for that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE` arises from a `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT`.  I suspect Boost.Lockfree has some size limit on the elements of the fifo.  Try again with a smaller UDT.

It may also be the case that Lockfree only works with standard types, so no UDT's will be accepted.  If that's case you need to store a pointer instead of the actual structure.